# Узнать, начался ли автоповтор

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания

Пишу программу, работающую без операционной системы. Нужно узнать, начался ли автоповтор нажатия клавиш PS/2 клавиатуры. Некоторое оборудование не посылает скан-код отпускания клавиши до окончания режима автоповтора, тогда всё просто, но некоторое (эмулятор Bochs) последовательно посылает скан-коды нажатия и отпускания. Вариант — следить за частотой появления символов и сравнивать с частотой автоповтора, но непонятно, как получить эту частоту автоповтора, разве что установить свою. Может, есть ещё варианты?

Ещё забыл упомянуть, что у меня в обработчике прерывания клавиатуры стоит большая задержка, то есть вариант со слежением за частотой будет работать не очень хорошо...

Comment: Может, проще подкрутить настройки Bochs?

Comment: @VladD а такая опция есть в настройках? Что-то я не нашёл.

Comment: Я не знаю, честно говоря, но раз он ведёт себя неправильно, это должно отключаться где-то. Попробуйте поменять модель эмулируемой клавиатуры, может, он притворяется какой-то экзотической железякой?

Comment: Вот [эта страница](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html) упоминает `nokeyrepeat`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, но эта опция вообще отключает автоповтор. Вообще странно, что она так называется, мне казалось, что стандартное название — typematic. Попробовал также все типы клавиатур, поведение то же.